# How to format my data to output in this format (mongodb /python)

Tags: python, mongodb

Right now i use this command :

```
restos.aggregate([{$unwind:"$categories"},
{$group:{_id:'$categories.title', count:{$sum:1}}}, 
{$project:{ type:"$_id", count: 1,_id:0}}])
```

which outputs me data like this :

```
{ "count" : 3, "type" : "Sandwiches" }
```

What i'd like is to have this instead:

```
{ "Sandwiches" : 3 }
```

How can i achieve this ? I am using python with pymongo, will i need to format it manually ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an stage into aggregation with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) like this:

```
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": [
        [
          {
            "k": "$type",
            "v": "$count"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1WlwvFbUY-o)